How to declare a method on a Python union type alias?
Suppose I have two classes, A and B:
class A:
  def f(self) -> bool:
    ...

class B:
  def f(self) -> bool:
    ...

And later I type alias these:
from typing import Union
FClass: TypeAlias = Union[A, B]

So that in another place I can have a function:
def g() -> FClass:
  ...  # Returns an object that is either A or B.


n = g()
n.f()  # This complains!

The call to f() here looks bad to checkers because f() is not declared on FClass even though it's declared on all possible types. Is there a way to declare the method will always exist on classes with that alias (something akin to a Java interface)? Or is there a better way to go about this? The specific complaint:
'A | B' has no attribute 'f'

Note that A and B are out of my control, as is the internals of g(). The practical use case is a multi-track library (i.e. 'alpha', 'beta', 'general audience') that have different generated internal objects, but that share an API.

Have you considered a prototype for a class providingf() such that both A and B fulfill it? (The typechecker can validate whether A and B fit the prototype without them explicitly declaring it, so it's okay that their implementation is outside your control).

Please provide a [mcve]. Depending on how you define g, you can also get an error with the definition of g itself, or there is no error at all.

@CharlesDuffy Prototypes are new to me! Thank you!

I think there's some misunderstanding of the issue here. If you wrote the example correctly, there would be no complaint like 'A | B' has no attribute 'f'. See mypy Playground, Pyright Playground. Don't forget self in instance methods!

What you want is a Protocol:
from typing import Protocol

class F(Protocol):
    def f() -> bool: ...

def g() -> F:
  ...  # Returns an object that implements f()


How does this get tied to A and B? I think I'm not seeing, just from this example, how this is different from me simply creating a new class with f() defined?

Without Protocol you wouldn't be able to have g() return an A.  Because F is a protocol, A and B conform to it as subtypes, even without declaring it as a parent.
